# When to use lifecycleScope.launch {}

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle, coroutinescope

I'm not clear on when and why we need to use   lifecycleScope.launch {}

I understand that this doesn't block the UI thread, but if you are doing UI work shouldn't you be doing it on the UIThread?

What about callbacks that are called everytime the UI is launch

Would you need to use this in a fragment's onViewCreated? Or what about an Activities onResume?

Comment: `lifecycleScope.launch` is fired on the `Dispatchers.Main` unless you specify another dispatcher. You can use `lifecycleScope` in Fragment but should use `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch { ... }` instead.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't quite answer my question.  What is the purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lifecycleScope is a coroutine scope that's used in activities and fragments (you should use viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope for fragments), every coroutine launched by lifecycleScope will be stopped when onDestroy() is called.